# How can I overrule default css settings on a:hover hyperlinked images?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a printer-friendly/PDF image that looks like this:

[image: printerfriendly]

Okay, simple enough. When hovering over it, however, the background turns gray, as I have my default hyperlinks set to this, for example:

```
#footer a:hover {
color: white;
background-color: #636363;
-moz-transition: all .6s linear;
-webkit-transition: all .6s linear;
-o-transition: all .6s linear;
transition: all .6s linear;
text-decoration: none;
outline: none;
}
```

So the question becomes, what css rule can I use on this WordPress domain to stop that background-color from happening?  I'd like **NO background color** when hovering over images.  Here's what I've tried:

```
.printfriendly a:hover img {
background-color: transparent !important;
opacity: 1.0 !important;
}
```

Among other things, but that just doesn't work.  Here is what I see in Firebug:

[image: printfriendly-firebug]

And when I right-click and "copy html" to that selection, this is the html output:

```
<div class="printfriendly pf-alignright"><a onclick="window.print();if(typeof(_gaq) !=    
'undefined') { _gaq.push(['_trackEvent','PRINTFRIENDLY', 'print', 'NULL']);} return false;" 
rel="nofollow" href="http://www.printfriendly.com/print?url=http://www.occupyhln.org/occupy-
hln-hall-of-heroes/"><img alt="Print Friendly" src="http://cdn.printfriendly.com/pf-button-
both.gif" style="border:none;-webkit-box-shadow:none; box-shadow:none;"></a></div>
```

So I'm pretty much at a loss -- which is happening less and less with CSS, as I'm learning more, experimenting and reading, but any help anybody can offer me as to how to get rid of that background-color when hovering over the print/pdf image would be greatly appreciated!  IF need be, there is an example here:  http://www.occupyhln.org/occupy-hln-hall-of-heroes/

Comment: div.printfriendly a:hover{background-color: transparent;}

Comment: That did it, Anon!  And it didn't mess with the text in the article.  Thanks for the knowledge!  Now time to study why you did what you did to make things work.  Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Answer (score 1):

The background colour is not on the image, but the link itself.

```
.entry-content a:hover { background: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks for that Nix!  That sets me in the proper direction; I don't know how you chose to use the selector .entry-content, but I'm learning.  The only problem I have is that ... that overrides the default hyperlinks in the actual article, which I don't want to do.  I just want to override the image hyperlink.  So I tried this:  .entry-content a:hover img { background-color:transparent!important; } but it's still not there .... appreciate your response!

Comment: don't use .entry-content class. In all blocks that have this class remove a:hover property